# Facebook shares same image with two different dimension

Tags: javascript, php, facebook, image

I am sharing an article(which having, image, title and description) using Facebook. My Image size is 486x509px. I know the image 1200 x 630px or greater will be displayed as large and the image  600 x 315px or lesser will displayed as smaller.

But my images are in between them. So it displayed as large for sometimes and small for sometimes. But I want to make my image to be shared as standard size either large or small. Is there any way to control the image size?

I am using the following url for sharing:

`'http://www.facebook.com/dialog/share?href=' + shareURL + '&app_id=' + fbAppID + '&redirect_uri=' + redirectURL + '&picture=' + mediaURL + '&caption=' + caption + '&description=' + description`

Please help me solve this problem. Thanks in advance.

Comment: just create special version of image for facebook

Comment: @Daimos. I have thousands of images. I think creating special version of images for facebook is wasting our storage capacity. Please let me know the possibility.

Comment: You case use the open graph protocol to set it

Comment: _“is wasting our storage capacity”_ – then don’t store it, but create it on-the-fly only.

Comment: @wilson I am not using the open graph protocol throughout my application. I am using the above URL for sharing. Is there any feasibility to do it without using Open Graph protocol?

Comment: Like @CBroe say , just create special version of image on the fly

Comment: @CBroe How can I create it on-the-fly only?

Comment: @wilson How can I create it on-the-fly only?

Comment: By not storing the manipulated image data to HDD, but outputting it to the requesting client only.

Answer (score -1):

So as [the facebook docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/share-dialog) says :

```
share Parameters
Parameter   Description
   href
```

The link attached to this post. Required when using method share. Include [open graph meta tags](http://ogp.me/) in the page at this URL to customize the story that is shared.

So you should add the meta tags from open graph protocol to your single page and set width and height

in others words, add open graph protocol to your `shareURL`ressource

Comment: I didn't vote down your question. Some other have voted down. Don't blame me.

Comment: I don't blame you @YASEERJAFFAR ;)